# Reporting system for Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I plan to migrate the backend of our android app from amazon+nginx+mysql to Firebase to get realtime updates, and we want to add a realtime reporting system hosted in Firebase, I googled it and seems https://keen.io can do the job, but I need to duplicate the data sending events to keen.io to use their dashboard templates. Somebody knows a better way to do it?

Best regards,

Christian